What is the actual difference between scales of the same notes?
I've recently been improvising on various scales, and one thing that I really don't understand is the difference between for example C Major and A Minor, or C Major and D Dorian scales. When I'm playing those scales I don't just play the notes up and down, so if I arbitrarily (per intuition) play the notes of each scale, there is no difference between them. Can someone explain the logic here? What is the difference in the scales for a composer except for the fact that usually the first and last notes are the tonics?

Tim is right. I'll just try to put it in different words.
The thing is that a scale isn't a circle of equals. There's a tone among the bunch occupying the position of their leader: the home tone, the tonal centre, the tonic, the root. If the leader of these seven is C, they form the scale of C major (also called C Ionian). If A is appointed as the leader, they become A minor (Aeolian) scale instead. Should G usurp the throne, they turn into G Mixolydian. Vote E into office, they regroup as E Phrygian.
Oh, but how do I tell which of them is ruling at the moment, you may ask.
In a given tune, you can typically identify a moment - usually at the very end, and most often also at the end of each verse - where it has come "home". You aren't getting any itches it should up and move somewhere else. It's resting, relaxed. At that moment, there'll be the tonal centre in the melody, and the tonic chord, rooted at this tone, in the harmony. If you listen to Imagine, "and the world will be as one" - the home tone is C. You're in C major (Ionian mode). If you listen to Lady in Black, "her long hair flowing in the midwinter wind" - the home tone is A. You're in A minor (Aeolian mode).
Other modes are uncommon, so I can't give you an example off the top of my head, at least not out of the modes of C major.

You've discovered modes!
Every major scale you know has 7 of them - the parent being the 1st, i.e. C major, which produces D Dorian, E Phrygian, F Lydian, G Mixolydian, A Aeolian and the almost unusable B Locrian modes.
Yes, they do all have the same set of notes, and yes, when playing them as modes, will start and end on the appropriate tonic.
So what?
Each has its own distinct flavour. For example D Dorian is a minor mode, as it contains D>F, a m3 interval. But it's not the same as D minor itself, as the IV chord is major, compared with the iv minor of actual D minor. Or, G Mixolydian (major mode) has a flattened 7th note (as used in many pop songs), rather than the one-semitone-below tonic in normal major keys.
To sound like you're actually in a mode, lots of visits to the tonic are necessary, and beginning/ending on that tonic certainly helps!
And of course, the chord set which accompanies each mode will differentiate it from its parallel major or minor scale.

I don't know about "parent" - how is C Ionian less of a mode of D Dorian than the other way around? I'd say they're both modes of each other.

@Divizna - fair question - but it's generally accepted that the parent is the 'pure' major scale/key. Ask the question on the site!

The difference isn't the collection of notes, but the note that is chosen by the composer as "tonic" (or whatever better name could be chosen for non-Common Practice Harmony, perhaps "keynote".) In the key of C major, the note C is (mostly) the final note of the piece or a main section. The chords on C emphasize this directly. Other chords "lead" to C chords (directly or indirectly). The pattern chord pattern, d-G-C, sounds like the finish of a part or whole. Were one to use the pattern b0-E-a, (with the chromatic alteration of the E chord) emphasize A as the final. (All notes from the chromatic scale can be used in any key, but the meanings of the notes are different.
Many details about these practices are contained in theory books.

OP asked specifically about notes from the major scale, not altered notes. Yes, we acknowledge that other notes do exist, but that's not the point of this question.


...so if I arbitrarily (per intuition) play the notes of each scale, there is no difference between them.

There should be a difference. An A played in C major should definitely have a "difference" from an A played in A minor. And, in the same way, a collection of pitches like C D E F G A B C, with a tonic of C and a major tonality, should sound "different" than A B C D E F G A, with a tonic of A and a minor tonality. The differences should be felt regardless of using just one collection of pitch letters.
The second of my two examples should be the more emphatic. A difference between a major and minor tonality should be very clear.
The first example is a bit subtler, but should also be clear. In C major the pitch C is the tonic and should have a feeling or resolution/rest, whereas the A should have an incomplete feel. These two feelings are the characteristic elements of an authentic cadence versus a "deceptive" cadence. If you were to change the key and play that "same" A in A minor, the feeling would change, and the A, as tonic, would now convey a feeling of resolution.
The "feeling", the function, of pitches changes when the tonic/key/mode changes. This change happens even if the collection of pitches is the same, because different treatment and emphasis is given to the pitches relative to the chosen tonic.

What is the difference in the scales for a composer except for the fact that usually the first and last notes are the tonics?

That exception is a huge difference and should not be disregarded. But, if you want to expand beyond that, probably the simplest way to do it would be to expand the single tonic pitch to the pitches of the tonic chord, and understand those are the stable pitches and the others are relatively unstable. That gives you a roughly 50/50 split of pitches between stable/unstable. That provides a very broad concept of pitch relationships. Think of it as a guiding principle while music is in a certain key/mode. A similar idea comes into play on a smaller, chord by chord basis. Chord pitches are generally stable (for consonant chords) while non-chord tones are unstable.
Just remember that relative relationships are very important in music. An A pitch is not simply an absolute value as might be expressed by a frequency, like all A4 are merely 440Hz. In musical terms a pitch in a key/mode is an identity formed by it's relationship to other pitches. A practical way to drive the concept home is to stop referring to pitches by letters and call them by their scale function names like "tonic", "supertonic", "mediant", etc. The concern for letter names will probably fade and be replaced with fundamental relative relationships like "leading tone resolves to tonic" or "subdominant resolves to mediant", etc.

Yes, any vaguely step-wise set of notes can be considered as several scales, depending on which note you decide to start on.
If we consider the 'white notes' set - C, D, E, F, G, A, B - we have seven choices.  We're probably most accustomed to hearing them as a C major scale, with A (natural) minor a close second.   (We're quite accustomed to the natural minor scale these days, an earlier generation, trained classically, might have felt that omitting the G♯ that would have completed A harmonic minor was an error.)   Next might come the modes starting on D and G.  Starting on E or F is a bit more 'outside', starting on B sounds definitely odd!  But they're all valid, and are in mainstream use in just about all styles of today's music.  (And always were in many traditions of folk music.)
